# What is an equivalent jQuery implementation of this Prototype Ajax.Updater call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

How would you create the same implementation in jQuery?

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('input_123', 
'/record/123', 
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind jQuery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your 'a' tag.

```
$(document).ready(){
  $('a#ajax').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax('/process.php', data);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        $('#input_123').load('/record/123');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I've never worked with prototype, but that's my best guess.  probably best to give your anchors an id, and use that to attach the behaviour though.

this is assuming that input_123 is the id of a something and what get's returned from /record/123 is html that goes in there...